# How do you use "Range" to Scan an entire table in accumulo

Tags: java, accumulo

How do you use "Range" to Scan an entire table in accumulo without apriori knowledge?

How do folks currently do that. I want to take the random search from:[I am looking at writing an Accumulo iterator to return a random sample of a percentile of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21503594/i-am-looking-at-writing-an-accumulo-iterator-to-return-a-random-sample-of-a-perc)

and scan over (then write to hdfs) a sample.

This requires me to scan the entire table I believe.

thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the same thing that the previous answer is saying, but I thought it might help to show a line of code.

If you have a scanner, cleverly named 'scanner', you can use the setRange() method to set the range on the scanner. Because the default range is (-inf, +inf), passing setRange a newly created range object will give your scanner, with a range of (-inf, +inf), the ability to scan the entire table.

The sample code looks like:

```
scanner.setRange(new Range());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can scan the entire table by using the no-arg constructor. Per the [docs](http://accumulo.apache.org/1.5/apidocs/org/apache/accumulo/core/data/Range.html#Range%28%29) on `Range()`:

`Creates a range that goes from negative to positive infinity.`

Comment: You should update this answer to also note that this is the default range if no other range is specified on the Scanner.

Comment: Milk you nailed it but Sweeney "Todd" at work hit me with in seconds after my entering it so I have to credit him as well. Thanks Mates, Chris